# Oh My Zsh - how to use GitHub plugin?

Tags: plugins, github, zsh, zshrc, oh-my-zsh

Just enabled [github plugin](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/github/github.plugin.zsh) in `.zshrc`:

```
plugins=(… guthub …)
```

After this autocomplete works fine, when I press `tab` I see:

[image]

But then, if, I try to run actual command, e.g.

```
github create test-repo
```

I'm getting

> zsh: command not found: github

Until now I used simple plugins only with aliases and I'm sure that I'm missing something here :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `github` plugin [contains this comment](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/github/_github#L4-L5):

> ```sh
> # in order to make this work, you will need to have the github gem installed
> # http://github.com/defunkt/github-gem
> ```

So to use it you'll need to install Ruby, then `gem install github`.